# Swift Alamofire + OAuth2 refresh token

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0, alamofire

Currently learning how to add OAuth2 via Alamofire and getting confused. I'm using the password grant type and when a request fails I understand that the retrier kicks in and requests a token refresh. The confusing part is which one do I use?

[Alamofire 4 using p2/OAuth2](https://github.com/p2/OAuth2/wiki/Alamofire-4)

[Alamofire RequestRetrier + Request Adapter](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/pull/1450)

The first one uses less code so unsure if its all the functionality I need. I also can't find a concrete example explaining this process.

I believe the following performs the refresh request?

```
private func refreshTokens(completion: RefreshCompletion) {
    guard !isRefreshing else { return }

    isRefreshing = true

    let urlString = "\(baseURLString)/oauth2/token"

    let parameters: [String: Any] = [
        "access_token": accessToken,
        "refresh_token": refreshToken,
        "client_id": clientID,
        "grant_type": "refresh_token"
    ]

    sessionManager.request(urlString, withMethod: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: .json).responseJSON { [weak self] response in
        guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

        if let json = response.result.value as? [String: String] {
            completion(true, json["access_token"], json["refresh_token"])
        } else {
            completion(false, nil, nil)
        }

        strongSelf.isRefreshing = false
    }
}
```

This is then passed back to adapt the previous request?

```
func should(_ manager: SessionManager, retry request: Request, with error: Error, completion: @escaping RequestRetryCompletion) {}
```

Is this the correct way of implementing this?

Thanks